# cumulative totals based on condition

Tags: sql-server-2008, conditional-statements

I am trying to get the cumulative totals based on some criteria. Below is a dummy sample data set. I would like to get the cumulative time based on the `Indicator` as well as `ID`. When the `Indicator` is continuously `1` for the same `ID`, I would like to get the sum of all the `Duration`. If it becomes `0` then I would like to restart.

```
ID  Duration    Indicator   Cumm_duration
1   30          0           30
1   30          1           60
1   30          0           30
1   30          0           30
1   30          1           60
1   30          0           30
1   30          0           30
1   30          0           30
1   30          0           30
1   30          0           30
1   30          0           30
1   30          0           30
1   30          1           60
1   30          1           90
2   30          1           30
2   30          0           30
2   30          0           30
2   30          0           30
2   30          1           60
2   30          0           30
2   30          1           60
2   30          0           30
2   30          0           30
2   30          0           30
2   30          1           60
2   30          1           90
2   30          0           30
```

Comment: 1. This'll be easier if you format your sample as a table with inserted data.
2. There is no column that indicates record order so it is impossible for the query to know in what order to process the indicators.

Comment: In order to get consistent results, you must have a column that you can order by.

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      ID INT ,
      Duration INT ,
      INDICATOR INT
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, 30, 0 ),
        ( 1, 30, 1 ),
        ( 1, 30, 0 ),
        ( 1, 30, 0 ),
        ( 1, 30, 1 ),
        ( 1, 30, 0 ),
        ( 1, 30, 0 ),
        ( 1, 30, 0 ),
        ( 1, 30, 0 ),
        ( 1, 30, 0 ),
        ( 1, 30, 0 ),
        ( 1, 30, 0 ),
        ( 1, 30, 1 ),
        ( 1, 30, 1 ),
        ( 2, 30, 1 ),
        ( 2, 30, 0 ),
        ( 2, 30, 0 ),
        ( 2, 30, 0 ),
        ( 2, 30, 1 ),
        ( 2, 30, 0 ),
        ( 2, 30, 1 ),
        ( 2, 30, 0 ),
        ( 2, 30, 0 ),
        ( 2, 30, 0 ),
        ( 2, 30, 1 ),
        ( 2, 30, 1 ),
        ( 2, 30, 0 );
```

Solution1(bruteforce):

```
with    indexed
          as ( select   * ,
                        row_number() over ( order by ( select null ) ) rn
               from     @t
             ),
        recursion
          as ( select   * ,
                        duration as cumulative
               from     indexed
               where    rn = 1
               union all
               select   t.* ,
                        case when t.indicator = 1 and t.id = r.id
                             then r.cumulative + t.duration
                             else t.duration
                        end
               from     indexed t
                        join recursion r on r.rn + 1 = t.rn
             )
    select  * from    recursion
    option  ( maxrecursion 0 )
```

Solution2:

```
with indexed as (select *, row_number() over (order by (select null)) rn from @t)
select *,
       (select sum(duration) from indexed i2
        where i1.id = i2.id and i2.rn <= i1.rn and 
              i2.rn >= isnull((select top 1 i3.rn from indexed i3
                               where i3.indicator = 0 and i3.rn <= i1.rn
                               order by i3.rn desc), 0))
from indexed i1
```